# TLP suspend my laptop everytime USB devices insterted when on battery

Tags: usb, suspend, power-management, battery, tlp

I'm using Kubuntu 21.10 in Acer 4736G laptop.

After installing tlp, when on battery power, my laptop always suspends every time I insert a USB devices (printer, flashdrive, bluetooth) and sometimes it also will not wake up after suspend.

What configuration should i change in tlp.conf to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the battery mode to balanced from the default value low battery.